# How to use intercept command for img tags in Cypress

Tags: cypress

When i log in to a page, an img tag loads with specific url for src attr. But i want the logo load another image in my local.
Is it possible to do by using intercept command before all tests?

I tried this. But not working.

```
cy.intercept('https://example.com/logo.png', {fixture: 'image.png'})
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's working (if you have a request for logo.png). `https://example.com` has no logo. You should test with a page that actually has an img, say `https://www.wikipedia.org/` - intercept the url `https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@1.5x.png` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should work just like you try. For example:

```js
  it('should intercept image', () => {
   // Intercept the image's URL and provide the image name in the `fixture` 
   cy.intercept('https://www.wikipedia.org/portal/wikipedia.org/assets/img/Wikipedia-logo-v2@2x.png', {
      fixture: 'cloud-logo.svg',
    });
    cy.visit('https://www.wikipedia.org');
  });
```

Make sure that your image is located in the `cypress/fixtures` folder.

[image: result]